# How to import bootstrap in django?

Tags: python, django

I have set up my python environment for coding, but I can't find the pip command to install Django in my virtual environment. I have tried to install it with pip install python3-django, as in the video I watched, but it simply doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question if extremely simple. the command is

```
python -m pip install django
```

I suppose that you are a beginner, but that is very very easy.